# Simple Message Client golang

Tags: go, stdout, stdin

So I've started a project which involves modules sending and receiving messages from a server via websockets. However I wanted a simple way for me to interact and send messages to the modules.

So I have the program ask for my message in a goroutine, when I hit enter, it sends the message and prompts me for another. In the main goroutine it will wait until it receives a message and when it does, write over the current line and replace what was on the line before on a new line.

There is only one problem, however. It don't know how to keep my input to place on the new line. In my testing with the following example, it seems that os.Stdin.Read halts until it receives a new-line character.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Input Buffer
    var msg string

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanBytes)

    go func() {
        for {
            // Prompt the user for a message
            fmt.Print("client1: ")

            // Scan os.Stdin, splitting on bytes
            for scanner.Scan() {
                if scanner.Text() == "\n" {
                    break
                } else {
                    // If the character is not \n, add to the input buffer
                    msg += scanner.Text()
                }
            }

            // Do something with the input buffer then clear it
            fmt.Println(msg)
            msg = ""
        }
    }()

    for {
        select {
        // Receive a message from a client
        case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            // Write the message over the current line
            fmt.Println("\rclient2: Hello")

            // Prompt the user again for their message
            // proving the current input buffer
            fmt.Print("client1: " + msg)
        }
    }
}
```

An example output:

```
client1: Hello!
Hello!
client2: Hello
client1: Bye!
Bye!
client2: Hello
client2: Hello // Was "client1: Good " before being overwritten
client1: Bye!
Good Bye!
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like IO race condition. Your goroutine is not synced with main. Btw ScanLines do the same for you. Consider this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    msgQ := make(chan string)

    defer close(msgQ)

    go func() {
        for {
            // Prompt the user for a message
            fmt.Print("client1: ")
            msg, ok := <-msgQ
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("\rclient1 said: " + msg)
            // Write the message over the current line
            fmt.Println("client2: Hello")
        }
    }()


    // Scan os.Stdin, splitting on bytes
    for scanner.Scan() {
        msgQ <- scanner.Text()
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** According to comments, this code shows what is wrong with that idea. When you write something and dont hit ENTER, client2 overwrites current line.. You can save(CTRL-U) and restore(CTRL-Y) current line but I did not find either ANSI signature or Signal to call it programatically.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    sendQ := make(chan struct{})

    defer close(sendQ)

    //simulate local client1 console
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Print("client1: ")
            select {
            case _, ok := <-sendQ:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
            case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
                fmt.Printf("\r\033[K") // delete current line from right
                fmt.Println("client2: Hello")
            }
        }
    }()

    for scanner.Scan() {
        sendQ <- struct{}{}
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm ok. Can't test it at the moment but it looks like that client2 can only output once you send a message. I'll play with the idea.

Comment: I dont think that terminal/console is not suitable for asynchronous IO operations. Alternative solution is ncurses or termbox..

Comment: I'm thinking as in my situation, messages are a lot more likely to be received than sent, I might just have a single terminal program for getting messages then another program for sending them. Thanks for your efforts. I did look at termbox but it feels like a lot of effort for not a huge problem.

Comment: It should be "I dont think that terminal/console suitable for asynchronous IO operations". Also you can see updated answer..